# How to provide credentials to Ankr when calling the API with Web3.js HttpProvider?

Tags: node.js, authorization, web3js

I am trying to get access to Ankr API address, which is like:

https://apis.ankr.com/XXXX/YYYY/full/main

When accessing this link by the browser I can introduce the credentials I created on Ankr panel control and I can pass successfully. However now I am trying to do this with Web3.js on Node:

```
var options = {
    headers: [
        {
            name: 'Authorization',
            value: 'Basic myUsername:myPassword',
        },],};

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://apis.ankr.com/XXXX/YYYY/full/main', options))
```

And I receive a 401 Unauthorized error response. I assume that my credentials are right because I could access them by the link on the browser, but not when passing in the header they seem not work. What is wrong in the code or what lacking of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the base64 of the `myUsername:myPassword`, not the actual plaintext.

```
// base64 encoded
value: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from('myUsername:myPassword').toString('base64'),
```

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) for more info.

Comment: Yes that's indeed much better than the hacky solution I found, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the credentials had to be hashed somehow.

I do not know if this is the most suitable solution, but I finally solved this by visiting the address on my browser (https://apis.ankr.com/XXXX/YYYY/full/main), opened dev tools on Chrome, and log in introducing my credentials.

Then I got the hashed credential sent on the request by checking the HEADER of my request (on Chrome, this is done in Network>therequest>Request Headers>authorization). I just copy/pasted this hashed credential on the js code and it worked!

Comment: Hashing is a one-way function (can't get the original back from a hash). Base64 is an **encoding** function (can be decoded back to the original). So in this case, the credentials are encoded, not hashed. Might be useful when you're looking for more resources.